# for each object array, how to add a field into it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

What I want is to insert a field index into my array

My code thar I receive my arrays is like that:

```
  const onFinish = (values) => {
       values.fields.map((el, idx) => {     
  console.log({ ...el, index: idx });
  //returns each object correctly, but how can I join these objects
     });

     addFields({ formName: 'TABLE NAME', fields: values.fields }).then(() => {
       //API CALL WHICH RETURNS A RESPONSE
     });
   };
```

`values.fields` is the array that I want to make it work

values.field array :

```
[
    {
        "field": "Peso do bezerro (kg)",
        "fieldtype": "Numeric"
    },
    {
        "field": "test",
        "fieldtype": "Text"
    },
    {
        "field": "Obs",
        "fieldtype": "Text"
    }
]
```

This array can have 'x' objects,What I want is for each add a field named index(`which will get if it's the first and add 0 if the second will add a 1 and following...`).Someone knows how to make it work ?

Comment: And the problem is what exactly? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: A simple `for` loop is all you need

Comment: @Andreas I tried to do an .map and a push,but it inserts it as an new object in my array and not a field in each object

Comment: Why `.map()`? And `.map()` doesn't push anything. But as already said: a `for` loop is all you need.

Comment: if you want witth map maybe like this `a.map((el,idx)=>{return{...el,index:idx}})`

Comment: @cmgchess that was it , how can I join these objects that returns now ? `I edited the question`

Comment: what do you mean by joining here

Comment: @cmgchess in the `console.log` I get the objects maped one after the other like this `{
    "field": "Peso",
    "fieldtype": "Numeric",
    "index": 0
}`       `{
    "field": "test",
    "fieldtype": "Text",
    "index": 1
}` as you see one after other , but how can I merge them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate for each item and add the index as shown below:

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
     console.log(values.fields);
     const fields = values.fields.map((item, index) => {...item, index});
     addFields({ formName: 'TABLE NAME', fields }).then(() => {
       //API CALL WHICH RETURNS A RESPONSE
     });
};
```

Comment: This creates a copy of `values.fields`. If you don't that copy you can use `.forEach()` instead of `.map()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function:

```js
const yourArray = [{
    "field": "Peso do bezerro (kg)",
    "fieldtype": "Numeric"
  },
  {
    "field": "test",
    "fieldtype": "Text"
  },
  {
    "field": "Obs",
    "fieldtype": "Text"
  }
]

yourArray.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.index = i + 1;
});

console.log(yourArray);
```